# C# code to search and result in xml

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I’m after some C# code that will have the following methods that will return Xml as the result.

Search the Apple iTunes App store.  If I pass it a name or partial name the function must return a list of possible search results or just one result if it is a perfect match.

Example shown below:

```
<App>

  <AppId>321564880</AppId>

  <Name>Doodle Clock - Clock A Doodle Do!</Name>

  <ReleaseDate>Released Sep 28, 2009</ReleaseDate>

  <Artist>YARG</Artist>

  <Description>Description of App</Description>

  <Copyright>Â© YARG Limited 2009</Copyright>

  <Price>$0.99</Price>

  <Category>Lifestyle</Category>

  <MainImageUrl><!—main App icon image urlà </ImageUrl>

  <ExtraImages>

       <!-- these will be the extra images you see in the App store other than the main application icon -->

       <ImageUrl> <!—url of extra image 1à</ImageUrl>

              <ImageUrl> <!—url of extra image 2à</ImageUrl>

              <ImageUrl> <!—url of extra image 3à</ImageUrl>

  </ExtraImages>

  <Version>Version: 1.1 (iPhone OS 3.0 Tested)</Version>

  <Size>1.5 MB</Size>

</App>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with at coded attempt to do that? I'm dont want to sound rude, but SO is not a coding machine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay the best way to create xml file and parse and manipulate them is using `XDocument`,`XElement`,etc. Because they are enumerable which means you can use LINQ on them and that will help you a lot.

For example :

```
XElement element = new XElement("Persons",
                                new XElement("Person","John",
                                             new XAttribute("Id","1")),
                                new XElement("Person","Aaron",
                                             new XAttribute("Id",2))
                                )
```

returns

```
<Persons>
 <Person Id="1">John</Person>
 <Person Id="2">Aaron</Person>
</Person>
```

More information : [`System.Xml.Linq Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.aspx)

If you are looking for speed, then you can use `XMLReader` and `XMLWriter` but you can't find the flexibility that `System.Xml.Linq` provides.

Comment: could you provide an entire c# funtion for this?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA, I would but I think what you are looking for is a dynamic list so whatever I wrote above, it would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPath in .NET:
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/.NET/Working-with-XPath-The-NET-Way/

Comment: can you provide me a sample script!?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(VS.71).aspx). It's the fastest way (though read-forward-only) - if you are maybe looking for speed. If not, XPath should do.